# laravel pass select option value to form action parameter

Tags: laravel

I am making a page with select option. 
If I select one option and click a button. It will go to that page with parameter in url.

I want to know is there any easy way to insert categoryId as parameter into action?

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('routename', ['categoryId' => 1]) }}">
@foreach($categories as $category)
<select>
    <option value="1">{{ $category->name }}</option>
    <option value="2">{{ $category->name }}</option>
    <option value="3">{{ $category->name }}</option>
</select>
@endforeach

<button>Change</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Because Blade uses PHP, and PHP is a back-end language, it won't run in your browser.

Instead you need javascript to deal with it which runs in the browser of the client.

Answer (score 2):

### You are being too specific in your route

You should remove the categoryId from the route. Instead you should point your route to a controller that just accepts a Request. then you can read the value of the select box in the controller and direct the user to the view depending on the selected option.

Your view:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('routename') }}">
@csrf
<select name='selectOption'>
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
</select>
@endforeach

<button>Change</button>

</form>
```

Your Route:

```
Route::get('url', 'Controller@functionName')->name('routename');
```

Your Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function functionName(Request $request)
{

  $option = $request->selectOption;

  if($option == 1){
    CODE FOR OPTION 1 HERE
  }
}
```

This way the route will not require the parameter to be defined in the URL. Instead you can pass it as a parameter in the request to be read in the controller. You could then have a if rule for each option that then returns a different view.